# PHP multidimensional array assignment with keys

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, key

Is it possible to assign variable values to keys while making a multidimensional array?
For example:

```
//creates array
$arr = array(
    'First' => array(),
    'Second' => array()
);

//assigns strings to variables
$name = 'First';
$once = 'Name';
$twice = 'Age';
$thrice = 'Whatever';

//loops twice to create arrays
do {
    $arr[$name][] = $once => array(), $twice => array(), $thrice => array();
    $once = 'Another';
    $twice = 'Example';
    $thrice = 'You get the point';
    if ($name == 'First') {
        $name = 'Second';
    } else {
        $name = 'end';
    }
} while ($name == 'Second');
```

The above example hardly makes sense to a living thing, let alone a piece of metal on my desk. If the above cannot be done with variables, how else could I create a multidimensional array with keys without explicitly coding it all out? Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
To clarify, here's a sample call to the array I'd like to make:

```
echo $arr['Second']['Another'][2];
```

The third dimensional part of the array would be assigned with a loop not included, i.e., the 2. I'm having difficulty creating the second dimension is all.

Comment: Maybe you could add what you expect the result to look like...? As you say, it makes little sense as is.

Answer (score 1):

I think that s what you are looking for

```
foreach ($arr as $key => &$value)
{
  $value[] = array('name' => 'test', 'age' => 28);
}
```